# Displaying local htm file in iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, path, src, pageload

I am saving some emails on my local machine using MailBee.NET Objects in htm format. A separate folder is created for each email using email messageID on server for example

D:\Emails\GmailId1380ec660e0e656a\doc.htm

is an email downloaded from gmail. I am saving also the above mentioned path in database so I can use it later. Now I am trying to display this htm file in an iframe but it is not working. A user clicks on email which takes him to the read_email page on which I am trying to assign the path mentioned above to an iframe but the iframe remains blank.

```
emailMessage.Attributes.Add("src",commandReader["email_message_path"].ToString());
```

emailMessage is the name of iframe and commandReader is normal SqlDataReader which I am using to read the path of the file mentioned above and then assigning that path to src attribute of iframe, I have placed this code in page_load event.

But as I said Iframe remains blank. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Post the result of commandReader["email_message_path"].ToString(). Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: using Response.Write(commandReader["email_message_page"].ToString()), I get D:\Emails\GmailId1380ec660e0e656a\doc.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local files are referenced with the `file` URI scheme. If your email message path is only `D:\Emails\...` then you'll have to prepend it with `file://` :

```
file://D:\Emails\...
```

Note that most browser will prevent you from including a **local file** from a **remote website** !.

Comment: But the website is also running on my development machine using ASP.net development server and even after deployment it will run on a local server on which the emails will be downloaded as well (The website is intended for internal office use only). A console app is made to download emails periodically and make database entries (runs via task scheduler) and the website is used to read those emails.

Comment: Running locally doesn't mean that you will be able to include files with the `file://` scheme, in fact Mozilla's browsers will **not** follow a `file://` link [if the page has been fetched via HTTP](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don't_Work). If the production server is the same remote machine where emails will be eventually stored, `file://` won't work since it **always** refers to the local filesystem of the client ! I suggest you to serve the HTML mail files through HTTP instead.

Comment: Ok I tested something, if I use the iframe in simple htm file then it calls other htm (email file) successfully, it doesn't even require the file:/// prefix, simple path like D:\\emails\\emailID\\doc.htm works. But if I use the same iframe in aspx file then it remains blank. I have tried placing/removing runat="server" attribute, tried to hardcode the src path, also tried using the file:/// prefix that you guys suggested but nothing works. However loading some http://.... page works in aspx file. I guess its security issue, any other suggestion before I drop the idea of downloading emails ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `file:///` before the path to the file?
Like `file:///D:\Emails\GmailId1380ec660e0e656a\doc.htm`

Comment: For some reason it is not being displayed even if the path is as you told me file:///D:\Emails\GmailId1380ec660e0e656a\doc.htm, surprisingly putting this path directly in src attribute of iframe is not working either but within visual studio if you ctrl + click the link it opens the right htm file which means the path is correct. This is really strange.

Comment: @user1469130 What happens if your path has a `#`, `@`, `[`, or `]` in the middle of it?