# iframe with local resource in Electron

Tags: iframe, electron

I need to render `iframe` in my Electron application:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe sandbox='allow-scripts' src='frm.html'></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

where the `frm.html` links the local file script `foo.js` which is part of my Electron application

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Inside iframe</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the application in Electron I can see this error in devtools console

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/electron/app1/foo.js
```

Is it possible such scenario in Electron?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a security feature of the iframe. Here is a similar question that talks about loading linked files into an iframe: [Displaying local htm file in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152103/displaying-local-htm-file-in-iframe).

That being said, have you considered using the webview tag instead? http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.30.0/api/web-view-tag/. The webview tag is very similar to an iframe, but gives you more ability to control the security around it. I tested loading a local file into a webview in the same way you attempt to load frm.html into the iframe and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Hey @shawn-rakowski , Your answer seems good. But I want to integrate external site which has its own heavy minified JS which assumes that it will be integrated within <iFrame> and communicates to main site every second. I dont even know how many times and from where it fires events which will be listened in main site. In that case can I use <webview> instead if <iframe>?

Comment: The webview tag as of now is not recommended as it's going through architectural changes. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag